# how to alter truncate-length in v-file-input of vuetify on responsive?

Tags: vuejs2, frontend, vuetify.js

I'm trying to create a form of file send, but i having problems with the 'truncate-length' property on responsive. I have set the property with 25, but on smartphones
I wish it were smaller. maybe 14.
sorry about my English, I'm Brazilian and i'm not fluent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easily replace it with `:truncate-length="length"` and specify `length` property in your Vue data.